# How does C++ STL _Hash class uses _Umap_traits and _Uhash_compare types?

Tags: c++, collections, stl, hashmap

We need to translate some old C++ code to C#. Where can I find more information about the following class? In particular, how it uses `_Umap_traits` and `_Uhash_compare` types?

https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/xhash

Comment: As both classes are implementation details the source is the best / only reference.

Comment: I cannot believe I cannot have an overview of the internals of this implementation. I also accept brief introductions by programmers that know it. Thank you.